# How to update / assign the `map` object with value?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How to iterate an array of objects and return a new object as expected?

In array there are 2 objects that are nested. I would like to create a new object by iterating those objects and return the new object.

I tried like this, but it does not work:

```
const props = datas.map(data => {
        props.data.bd.locale = data;
}, {}); //new object required
```

Comment: Can you provide example data? What have you got, and what do you want to turn it in to?

Comment: here is my try : https://jsfiddle.net/vjpj1f06/1/  I agree that, I am not clear here. just i requrie to create a new object using the array of objects name value

Comment: what is your expected output ? as that array doesn't contain any nested object

Comment: in the (not included) example, you create a circular reference.

Comment: @3gwebtrain: Please update your question with the sample data.

Comment: `map` creates new array (which is an object by the way). The second argument to map is context to be used to call iteratee function with. But in your example it makes no effect because you are using an arrow function that captures context once and for all. Also map is not intended to do side effects like external object mutation. I do recommend to read [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to create an object from an array of objects. In this case, you can do it like this:

```
const props = datas.reduce((total, data) => {
    total[data.id] = data;

    return total;
}, {});
```

Where `total` is a new object. Keep in mind to use unique identifiers or so.

Answer (score 0):

It's works for me:

```
const props:any = {}

datas.map(data => {
var label = data.bd.locale;
   return props[label] = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of reduce to do create a new object

```
const props = datas.reduce((acc, data) => {
      acc[data.bd.locale] = data;
      return acc
}, {}); 

console.log(props);
```

or simply make use of forEach

```
const props = {}
datas.forEach((acc, data) => {
        props[data.bd.locale] = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have this:

```javascript
const datas = [
    {
        fname: "jane",
        lname: "dane",
        description: {
            eyes: "blue",
            skin: "pale"
        }
    },
    {
        fname: "john",
        lname: "doe",
        description: {
            eyes: "black",
            skin: "brown"
        }
    }
]
```

and then you want to change all their `eyes` into "green":

```javascript
const props = datas.map(item=>{
    const temp = {...item, description: { ...item.description, eyes: "green" } }
    return temp
})
```

you will have the result:

```javascript
const datas = [
    {
        fname: "jane",
        lname: "dane",
        description: {
            eyes: "green",
            skin: "pale"
        }
    },
    {
        fname: "john",
        lname: "doe",
        description: {
            eyes: "green",
            skin: "brown"
        }
    }
]
```

this way, you are not mutating the value of datas and at the same time, you are creating a mutated instance of it.

OR if you're not working with a nested object let's say:

```javascript
const datas = [
    {
        fname: "jane",
        lname: "dane"
    },
    {
        fname: "john",
        lname: "doe"
    }
]
```

and then you want to change all their `lname` into `awesome`:

```javascript
const props = datas.map(item=>{
    const temp = {...item, lname: 'awesome' }
    return temp
})
```